# find printf unable to print newlines or carriage returns

Tags: linux, bash

I am making a script to check and list the outputs of certain files in our job folder. I am wanting to check files that have been there today (or in the past 24 hours I guess).

Currently I am doing the following:

```
 find /folder/jobfolder/rrz* -type f -mtime 0
```

so I get something like this:

```
/folder/jobfolder/rrzabc_1234.lis
/folder/jobfolder/rrzdef_4567.lis
/folder/jobfolder/rrzgre_8901.log
```

ideally I would like to use the printf command to add the date to it so I can see if it was today and separate it line by line. If I do

find `/folder/jobfolder/rrz* -type f -mtime 0 -printf %p\t%AD\n` It does not take use the escape characters.

```
/folder/jobfolder/rrzabc_1234.lis/folder/jobfolder/rrzdef_4567.lis/folder/jobfolder/rrzgre_8901.log
```

Is there a better way to approach this? also being able to use `-iname` to match capital or lowercase letters might be helpful

Comment: Did you try `%p\\t%AD\\n`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are missing quotes; try

```
 -printf '%p\t%AD\n'
```

so that bash does not interpret the `\`

Comment: wow that was a simple fix.  I shouldve thought of that. thanks man